# Excel formulas not updating?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I ran a couple of macros. Used different options to update the calculation in the excel formulas but it still isn't working. I also pressed CRTL+ALT+SHIFT+F9, also updated calculation settings to automatic to no avail.

Excel file formulas not working in all sheets check P17:P35 for example

Comment: Please do not include links to your file. Instead, include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: What happens in your "couple of macros" ?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your macro, try running:
`Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

If that code is missing it could impact the appearance of formulae updating. This could be because your macros are missing that or an error prevented it from running.

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating` is not "sticky" and does not need to be set back to True at then end of your code.

Comment: Unless there is a version difference in Excel, it absolutely does stick.  ```Also, don’t forget to set Application.ScreenUpdating = True at the end of your macro. If you leave it set to False, then your users might think that the worksheet is broken. This is because when you have auto-calculated values (like formulas), they won’t be updated unless you perform a “Calculate Sheet” by using F9 (or in the Formulas group in the ribbon).``` https://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/use-application-screenupdating-speed-code/

Comment: Can you replicate that problem?  I can't, and I don't believe I've ever seen that happen...

Comment: Setting it to true will only make a difference if the VBA has a `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` further up the stack.

Comment: @TimWilliams, my assumption is that the user turned it off but didn't turn it back on. Are you assuming something else? You can replicate this issue by turning it off in VBA, but not turning it back on.

Comment: @spikey_richie true, unless it's a macro-enabled file where a prior user turned off screenupdating and saved the results.

Comment: I tested by setting calculation to manual and screenupdating to False, then updating the sheet and turning calculation back to automatic (but not resetting screenupdating).  After the sub had run, screenupdating was `True` and the worksheet showed the current calculations.   So, I can't reproduce the problem described in the link you posted.

Comment: @TimWilliams I just ran the code in Office 365, and this issue appears to not impact 365.

Comment: I just tested in Excel 2010 and it doesn't cause any problem there either.  It's possible it may once have been a problem, but I've been working in Excel VBA for many years and have never experienced that issue.

Comment: I've seen this numerous times over the years with 2010 and 2013. I looked for an update from Microsoft but haven't found one yet. Just found a conversation on this topic: https://www.atlaspm.com/toms-tutorials-for-excel/toms-tutorials-for-excel-why-reset-screenupdating-to-true-heres-why/